# Acessing auth user attribute

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am in the guzzle controller making a request to an external api.

I wanna use an id from the user who is logged in.

I have been doing the request with a `static id`, but now i want it dynamically.

I tried like this:

```
    $science = Auth::user()->science_id;

    $client = new Client(['headers' => ['Accept' => 'application/json']]);

    $request = $client->get(
        'https://url_to_the_api/'.$science.'/degree',
        [
            'auth'          => ['client', 'secret'],
        ]

    );

    $data = $request->getBody()->getContents();

    return $data;
```

And i have the error

> 500(internal server error)

and this message:

> "Trying to get property 'science_id' of non-object"

What am i missing?

Thanks for your time

Comment: Are you logged in?

Comment: Rouhollah i am ahahah

Comment: Make sure 'science_id' column name is same in user table.

Comment: It is Arun J, it seems like it is not detecting the fact that i am logged in, not sure why

Comment: Where are you writing this code? Which route are you requesting when you're running this code? Are the route being guarded by an `auth` middleware?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using it in web app then make sure you first check if user is already authenticated by using **auth middleware** or manually by using `Auth::check()` function.

Or

If you are trying to hit this by api that will not work here because session will not be maintained in that case. That's why **JWT tokens** were introduced to maintain the state of an application.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it like this:

```
  $science = auth('api')->user()->science_id;
```

Thanks for the help!